# migration oracle to postgresql invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

Tags: oracle, postgresql, utf-8, plpgsql, oracle-fdw

Im migrating an application from oracle to postgresql. In one of the functions that I already migrated I copy data from a different oracle db (db link in oracle, oracle_fdw extension in postgresql) from a few tables into a local table in my postgresql db. However, I`m getting the next error :

`invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00`

I saw that some people had this kind of issue in this forum but they didnt try to copy the data directly from a remote database (they loaded data from a dump or from a csv..).

Some kind of idea what can I do ?

Comment: What is the Oracle DB encoding?

Comment: nls_characterset : IW8ISO8859P8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not allow the “zero” character in character strings.

You'll have to sanitize the Oracle data before you can retrieve them from PostgreSQL.

Comment: What does it mean "Zero" character ? How can I filter the data before it comes to postgresql ? I run in postgresql the query insert into local_table select * from remote_table

Comment: With "zero character" I mean the character with ASCII (or UNICODE) code point 0. Ther error is thrown during the select from `remote_table` - some string column there contains such a character. You'll have to fix the data on the Oracle side.

Comment: I think that those just varchar columns that dont have any value - the null of varchar. So what exactly do I need to change ?

Comment: No, a NULL value would not be a problem. If you select the offending value like this in Oracle: `SELECT dump(badcol, 16) FROM atable WHERE id = 42` you will see a byte 0x00 somewhere in there. That is the problem (replace `badcol`, `atable`, `id` and 42 with relevant values for your situation).

Comment: The error I got in postgresql doesnt specify which row has the problem - only the table_name and the column. How can I proceed from here ? for exmaple : insert into MANUIM select * from MANUIM_prod;
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
CONTEXT:  converting column "street" for foreign table scan of "manuim_prod", row 922311

Comment: If you `select * from remote_table`, you will get an error message like `converting column "badcol" for foreign table scan of "remote_table", row 4711` that will show you which row contains the problem.

Comment: yes but then I need to switch the id you mentioned with rownum ?

Comment: You can find the offending columns win Oracle with a query like `SELECT id FROM oratable WHERE badcol LIKE '%' || CHR(0) || '%'`

Comment: Correct, PostgreSQL does not support the null byte `\0` in text/varchar strings; see e.g. `SELECT E'\0'`. If you need to store arbitrary binary data use `bytea`, which *can* store null bytes. If you're just storing badly encoded text, fix your data to comply with utf-8.

Comment: This zero unicode character is space ? Because the value I have in the problematic column is just space -> ' ' . Is there a way to use decode to solve this ?

Comment: I tried to implement a solution and it failed. I posted a new post about it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45297296/postgresql-9-5-decode-select-case-to-solve-error-with-utf8-doesnt-work

Answer (score 2):

Now it works with oracle_fdw 2.3.+
Here is code I used

```
select 'ALTER FOREIGN TABLE "'||table_schema||'"."'||table_name||'" ALTER COLUMN "'||column_name||'"  OPTIONS (ADD strip_zeros ''true'');' 
from information_schema."columns" c 
where table_name ='my_foreign_table_name'
and table_schema ='my_schema_name_where_foreign_table_created'
and udt_name in ('varchar', 'bpchar');
```